# Custom data filter on FuelUX datagrid not updating data display with results

Tags: datagrid, datasource, filtering, fuelux

I am trying to implement a filter on my custom datasource for a FuelUX datagrid.

It filters the data properly but leaves it paginated as though it was not filtered. I.E. I have to either increase the results per page or go to the next page to see the results.

How do I get the grid to update to display the filtered results properly?

Here is my custom filter function:

```
            if (options.filter) {                   
                data = data.filter(function (item) {
                    switch( options.filter.value )
                    {
                        case "all":
                            return true;
                        break;

                        default:
                            return item.contentID == options.filter.value;
                        break;
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good catch!  I have entered an issue for this at https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/issues/143

In the meantime, just add this logic after you load Fuel UX but before you initialize your datagrid.

```js
$.fn.datagrid.Constructor.prototype.filterChanged = function (e, filter) {
    this.options.dataOptions.filter = filter;
    this.options.dataOptions.pageIndex = 0;
    this.renderData();
};
```

Thank you for the report.

Comment: Ok. That works. Thank you. I'm also showing some strangeness in the pagination. Example: 1 - 050 of 95 items. Also, I can go to page -1. The previous button doesn't get disabled when going to the first page.

Comment: Disregard the end of my comment. I had an error in my datasource that caused the funky behavior.